# can't see edited info in user info panel

Tags: php

I made a page for user info containing a button for updating their info. When I change the fields and push the button, the info changed in the database and the web page shows everything is ok and changed, but when I refresh the page (after pushing the button), there the fields aren't changed and contain still the same info (but changed in data base). So how can I solve this?

Here is html codes:

```
<div class="custom-container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-10">

                <div class="user_content custom-container">

                    <div class="row">

                        <div class="col-11 fields">

                            <form method="post" action="user_updates.php">

                                <fieldset id="right">

                                    <label>نام کاربری</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["member_username"] ?>" disabled style="direction: ltr;">

                                    <br><br>

                                    <label>رمز عبور</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["member_password"] ?>" style="direction: ltr;">

                                    <br><br>

                                    <label>نام</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" name="first-name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["member_name"] ?>">

                                    <br><br>

                                    <label>نام خانوادگی</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" name="last-name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["member_last_name"] ?>">

                                </fieldset>

                                <fieldset id="left">

                                    <label>نام پدر</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" name="father-name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["member_father_name"] ?>">

                                    <br><br>

                                    <label>کد ملی</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" name="melli-code" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["member_melli_code"] ?>" style="direction: ltr; font-family: Iran_Sans_M;">

                                    <br><br>

                                    <label>شماره موبایل</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="text" name="mobile-number" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["member_mobile_number"] ?>" style="direction: ltr; font-family: Iran_Sans_M;">

                                    <br><br>

                                    <label>ایمیل</label>
                                    <br>
                                    <input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["member_email"] ?>" style="direction: ltr;">

                                </fieldset>

                                <input type="hidden" name="user-id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION["member_id"] ?>">

                                <input type="submit" name="change" value="ثبت تغییرات">

                            </form>

                            <?php 

                                if (isset($_GET["empty"]))
                                {
                                    echo '<div class="php_texts"> <p>لطفاً تمامی قسمت ها رو پر نمایید.</p> </div>';
                                }

                                if (isset($_GET["changes"]))
                                {
                                    echo '<div class="php_texts"> <p>اطلاعات با موفقیت ویرایش شد.</p> </div>';
                                }

                                if (isset($_GET["error"]))
                                {
                                    echo '<div class="php_texts"> <p>عدم ارتباط با سرور.</p> </div>';
                                }

                            ?>

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div> <!-- User Content-->

            </div> <!-- User Content-->
```

and here is php codes:

```
<!-- General Codes-->

include("connect_to_sql.php");
session_start();
```

```
if(isset($_POST["change"]))
{
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $first_name = $_POST["first-name"];
    $last_name = $_POST["last-name"];
    $father_name = $_POST["father-name"];
    $melli_code = $_POST["melli-code"];
    $mobile_number = $_POST["mobile-number"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $id = $_POST["user-id"];

    if (empty($username) && empty($password) && empty($first_name) && empty($last_name) && empty($father_name) && empty($melli_code) && empty($mobile_number) && empty($email))
    {
        header("location:user_changes.php?empty=fill+all+fields");
        exit;
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION["member_username"]))
    {
        $member_update= "UPDATE `member_info` SET `password` = '".$password."', `first_name` = '".$first_name."', `last_name` = '".$last_name."', `father_name` = '".$father_name."', `melli_code` = '".$melli_code."', `mobile_number` = '".$mobile_number."', `email` = '".$email."' WHERE `member_info`.`id` = '".$id."';";
        $member_query = mysqli_query($connect_to_mysql,$member_update);
        #$member_fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($member_query);

        if($member_query)
        {
            header("location:user_changes.php?changes=ok");
            exit;
        }
        else
        {
            header("location:user_changes.php?error=data+base");
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is all that code in ONE php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you read the information for the user from the session, but never write the updated data into the session.

So either rewrite the values to the session in the `if($member_query)` block or fetch and map the actual values from the database on each page load to the session.

Another huge issue of your code is that it's vulnerable for SQL Injection attacks.